# date-time-string to UNIX time with milliseconds

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, unix-timestamp

I need to convert a date/time string to UNIX timestamp including the milliseconds. As the timetuple() does not include milli or microseconds I made a short workaround. But I was wondering, is there a better/nicer way to do this?

```
import datetime as dt
import time

timestamp = '2018-01-19 10:00:00.019'  # example of input time string 
tmp       = timestamp.split('.')
millisec  = tmp[-1]                    # extracting only milli-seconds
UX_time = time.mktime(dt.datetime.strptime(tmp[0], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').timetuple()) + float(millisec)/1e3

print(UX_time)
```

> 1516352400.019

I realize my timezone is off by one hour, so you might be getting

```
print(UX_time)
```

> 1516356000.019

Comment: @slashcool My original code was time.mktime(dt.datetime.strptime(tmp[0], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f').timetuple()) when I noticed that timetuple() does cut off microseconds. This is the reaason for this change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:

```
timestamp = '2018-01-19 10:00:00.019' 
tmp=np.datetime64(timestamp)
print(tmp.view('<i8')/1e3)
```

output:

```
1516352400.019
```

Comment: Didn't know about numpy.datetime64() before. Thanks, it's doing exactly what I need it to be doing.

Answer (score 0):

Also possible with your current code:

```
import datetime as dt
import time

timestamp = '2018-01-19 10:00:00.019'  # example of input time string 
ts = dt.datetime.strptime(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
UX_time = time.mktime(ts.timetuple()) + ts.microsecond/1e6

print "%.3f" %UX_time
```

Comment: I like the stile, it's shorter than my code. But in comparison with the code of @riccardo nizzolo it's a bit slower.